# is it possible to create maven profile based on property file in classpath

Tags: maven

I am new to maven profiles and am trying to create some different profiles in my pom file for my spring mvc webapp.

I have a property file in my classpath named env.properties. It lives in ...

Project Root>src>main>resources

And the content looks like this....

```
#spring.profiles.active=mock
#spring.profiles.active=test
spring.profiles.active=server
```

Is it possible to create my maven profile based on this file? 
i.e. if spring.profiles.active=server is uncommitted so then the active profile is server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it acceptable to work the other way around?

as in, you set the properties in the pom.xml then generate the configuration file using this maven plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html

I don't think it will work by loading the file around because the plugin would load the properties after the project profile is set

Comment: thanks for this feedback, you have lead me down the right path although i am having some troubles on finding examples on how to use it. I might ask another question specific to this.